# How to change a parameter if a class exception is thrown in a subclass java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

This really seems a weird question but trully I couldn't figure out a better way to ask it.
I have made a class called Brand that throws invalid name exception when the name is null or empty, just like this (only the constructor):

```
public Brand(String name, String producer, String region) throws ExInvalidBrand {
    if (name == null || name.equals("")) {
        throw new ExInvalidBrand("Brand name cannot be empty or null!");
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.producer = producer;
    this.region = region;
}
```

Now I need to create a subclass out of this, which is supposed to throw the same exception but when thrown, has to change its name to "White Brand".
The constructor of the subclass is:

```
public CommercialBrand(String name, String producer, String region) throws ExInvalidBrand{
    super(name, producer, region);
}
```

As i see this, i need to use the super keyword so I actually inherit their variables.
The subclass throws the Exception as expected when the name is empty.

The only way I know is create a new constructor in the main class that doesn't ask for the name and then calling that one in the subclass, also creating a new private variable name and try/catching the exception in there.

Can it be done with the constructor as i have it right now?

This is a really weird question, I'm happy to clarify anything I can about this.

EDIT: I've noticed that I probably did not explain myself well.

Imagine that we have this psvm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExInvalidBrand {
    Brand br = new Brand("brand1", "producer1", "region1"); //here an object is created with the name = brand1, producer = producer1 and region = region1
    CommercialBrand cb = new CommercialBrand("brand1", "producer1" , "region1"); // same as above, but now from the subclass.
    CommercialBrand cbWithNoName = CommercialBrand("", "producer1", "region1"); 
}
```

This is what I want. When this happens, the object cbWithNoName should be created nonetheless, and give it the name "White Brand" when the exception is thrown.
A try/catch before the super, would be great, something like this, **if this was possible, which is not**, as far as I know.

```
public MarcaComercial(String name, String producer, String region) throws ExInvalidBrand{
    try {
        super(name, producer, region);
    } catch (ExMarcaInvalida ex) {
        super("WhiteBrand", producer, region);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to change exactly? The exception text?

Comment: Also use name instead brand property in constructor of Brand class

Comment: So you want to wrap the `super(...)` call in a try block? If that's the case, see [Why can't I use a try block around my super call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328/why-cant-i-use-a-try-block-around-my-super-call)

Comment: The thing that i want to change is the name that the subclass gets. Basically, if it the exception is not thrown, i want to keep the name as it was in the parameter, but if it does throw an exception, i want to make it "White brand". A try catch on the super was my first idea, but the super has to be the first thing that a constructor gets, as far as I know (Edit was a simple correction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator in the call to `super()` in the `CommercialBrand` constructor.

```java
public CommercialBrand(String name, String producer, String region) throws Exception {
    super((name == null || name.equals("") ? "WhiteBrand" : name), producer, region);
}
```

Comment: And if OP wouldn't want to duplicate the name checking, it could be moved to a separate method in base class, which would check the name validity.