Fatal Exception: android.util.SuperNotCalledException
I used try-catch block for avoiding androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.InstantiationException error, which occurs when the Android system kills my app and I want to open the app from the background. I found some solution, which was solved by using the try-catch block.
My app is live now, and I used React Native to build this app. I found this issue from crashlytics; that's why I can't reproduce the issue also.
This is the issue I found from crashlytics:
{au.com.credsys.planability/au.com.credsys.planability.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
Fatal Exception: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {au.com.credsys.planability/au.com.credsys.planability.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4154)

This is my Code:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } catch (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.InstantiationException e) {
        System.out.println("Error on Loading App from Background: " + e);
    }

    String rootDir = MMKV.initialize(this);
    new au.com.credsys.planability.RNDynamicSplash(this);

    if (isTablet()) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}


sorry, already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328/why-cant-i-use-a-try-block-around-my-super-call (i'll raise a flag, no worry) thanks for providing your question and sharing your probem!!!

This question is similar to: Why can't I use a try block around my super() call?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
